# Cutting Vines in Halacha

Tags: halacha, grapes-wine, trees, bal-tashchit-waste, environment

Halacha does not allow one to cut down a Fruit Bearing tree. Does this apply to a Grape Vine too?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that grape vines are considered Halachically indistinguishable from trees.

Comment: @Isaac Moses - Does that mean cutting down flax is out too?

Comment: Borei Peri HaEtz on grapes IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

It applies to any productive object that is destroyed for a non-productive purpose. [Rambam Melachim 6:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=6&halocha=10&hilite=)