# Should Jews be environmentalists?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, environment

Do we have a religious obligation to take care of the environment, and if so how far does it extend?  Should I spend money to decrease my carbon footprint?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30968/759

Comment: @DoubleAA for sure part 2 of mine is not duped.  But I think I asked part 1 better than he did.

Comment: I'm going to put it on hold while we sort this out to avoid more answers

Comment: You can edit your post to undupe it or emphasize the non-dupe part and how it's not duped. Also we can consider merging the answers one way or the other.

Comment: @DoubleAA Sure.  Does my addition about spending money not qualify?

Comment: There's a lecture about this on jml.org.au